# How to track a program that changes the window focus

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, fullscreen, window-focus

I have a newly reformatted PC and I just finished installing all the programs, drivers and hardware applications (like samsung magician, Logitech gaming software, etc) that I needed.

I work with 2 monitors and tons of windows opened (I'm programming)

Now one strange behavior that I'm getting annoyed is sometimes, the window focus randomly changes. I'm not sure what program has been doing this and I don't want to uninstall programs 1 by 1 to catch the offending program (since this was not happening on the previous OS installation given the same programs and startup, the only difference is everything is updated in the new OS format).

I haven't timed it yet, but it happens approx once every 20min
Same thing happens to games, randomly going out of full-screen. (I know samsung magician has this behavior before, but I tried to remove it on startup and games still randomly goes out of full-screen)

I would like to know if there's an elegant solution to catch what program/driver/hardware application is doing this because it's getting annoying.

I'm using windows 8.1 fully updated, I formatted my pc to upgrade from win 8.1 also (but probably around 1 year behind on updates) since I usually reformat a windows OS every 1.5 years.

Comment: oh nice, just what I've been looking for! I'm currently running happydroid from the suggested tools http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=27767&PID=143093&title=figuring-out-whats-stealing-window-focus#143093 . Hopefully this is a better solution since waiting for the program to do the focus stealing with process explorer is quite tedious.

Answer (score 6):

Solved it,

It was HD-Frontend.exe (Bluestacks executable) that seems to be the culprit.
It wasn't happening before so I'm just going to quit the bluestacks icon toolbar when not in use.

Used this [Program](http://www.happydroid.com/focus) to catch it